# configure Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration" using CLI / groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, configuration, command-line-interface

Is there a way to configure ANT- and MAVEN-Installations using CLI? For the JDK there is:

```
dis = new hudson.model.JDK.DescriptorImpl();
dis.setInstallations( new hudson.model.JDK("JDK8", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk"));
```

Tobi

Answer (score 3):

It the way to set maven using Groovy:

```
    def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()    
    def desc = inst.getDescriptor("hudson.tasks.Maven")
    def minst =  new hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstallation("Maven_name", "maven_path");
    desc.setInstallations(minst)
    desc.save()
```

Comment: how will I be able to add a tool which is not Maven and Java? these 2 have a dedicated implementation...

Comment: which you want to add

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the corresponding descriptors by manually changing `Global Tool Configuration` and then looking at the xml config files created in `JENKINS_HOME`.

For example, for Maven it must be `hudson.tasks.Maven.DescriptorImpl` and for Ant - `hudson.tasks.Ant.DescriptorImpl`